# Java - List Collection with multilevel classes - only loops last member - .stream() .forEach() .for()

Tags: java, class, object, collections, java-stream

I've got a question that kept me up way too long last night :)
I've made a multilevel class like:

- Layer

  - LayerImage
  - LayerHalftone

    - LayerHalftoneVideo
    - LayerHalftoneImage

#### The approach

- The objects are created in settings.java
- and added to the "layers" collection list.
- In main.java I try to aggregate them via 3 ways.

#### The problem

None of the aggregates work (read: give the desired result) **They all only loop the last member of the collection list.**

**My question** would be, where do I go wrong? What do I need to change to get this working?

*I'm sorry for the long code. I've tried to make it as compact as possible for this illustration.*

#### Console result

```
5
[LayerHalftoneVideo@61bbe9ba, LayerHalftoneVideo@610455d6, LayerHalftoneVideo@511d50c0, LayerHalftoneImage@60e53b93, LayerImage@5e2de80c]
LayerHalftoneVideo@511d50c0
title 01

.forEach()
title 01
title 01
title 01
title 01
title 01

.stream()
title 01
title 01
title 01
title 01
title 01

.for()
title 01
title 01
title 01
title 01
title 01
```

#### Console Desired result

(for each loop type)

```
smoke
video 01
video 02
image 01
title 01
```

**main.java**

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // debug to see amount of elements in list
        System.out.println( settings.layers.size() );
        System.out.println( settings.layers );
        System.out.println( settings.layers.get(2) );
        System.out.println( settings.layers.get(2).idReadable );

        System.out.println( "\n.forEach() ");
        settings.layers.forEach( layer -> {
            System.out.println( layer.idReadable);
        });

        System.out.println( "\n.stream() ");
        settings.layers
                .stream()
                .forEach( layer -> {
                    System.out.println( layer.idReadable);
                });

        System.out.println( "\n.for() ");
        for (Layer layer : settings.layers) {
            System.out.println( layer.idReadable );
        }
    }
}
```

**settings.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class settings extends main {

    public static List<Layer> layers = new ArrayList<>();

    static {

        layers.add(new LayerHalftoneVideo(
                "smoke",
                false,
                "video/smoke_02.mp4",
                1000,
                1414,
                1,
                0,
                30,
                50,
                0,
                new int[] { 255,255,255 },//color_03,
                30,
                1.0f
        ));

        layers.add(new LayerHalftoneVideo(
                "video 01",
                true,
                "video/01.mp4",
                1000,
                1414,
                1,
                0,
                40,
                80,
                1,
                new int[] { 255,255,255 },//color_02,
                30,
                1.0f
        ));

        layers.add(new LayerHalftoneVideo(
                "video 02",
                true,
                "video/02.mp4",
                1000,
                1414,
                1,
                0,
                0,
                100,
                1,
                new int[] { 255,255,255 },//color_00,
                30,
                1.0f
        ));

        layers.add(new LayerHalftoneImage(
                "image 01",
                false,
                "illustration/1.jpg",
                1000,
                1414,
                1,
                0,
                20,
                80,
                1,
                new int[] { 255,255,255 }//color_02
        ));

        layers.add(new LayerImage(
                "title 01",
                true,
                "image/title_01.png"
        ));

    }
}
```

**Layer.java**

```
public abstract class Layer {

    static String    idReadable;
    static boolean   runThisLayer;
    static String    inputPath;

    public Layer(
            String  _idReadable,
            boolean _runThisLayer,
            String  _inputPath
    ) {
        idReadable      = _idReadable;
        runThisLayer    = _runThisLayer;
        inputPath       = _inputPath;
    }

}
```

**LayerImage.java**

```
public class LayerImage extends Layer {

    public LayerImage(
            String  _idReadable,
            boolean _runThisLayer,
            String  _inputPath
    ) {
        super(
                _idReadable,
                _runThisLayer,
                _inputPath
        );
    }

}
```

**LayerHalftone.java**

```
public class LayerHalftone extends Layer {

    static int       inputWidth;
    static int       inputHeight;
    static int       patternOffset;
    static int       patternSkipEach;
    static int       patternAngleRadian;
    static int       patternBlockAmount;
    static int       patternNumber;
    static int[]     patternColor;

    public LayerHalftone(
            String  _idReadable,
            boolean _runThisLayer,
            String  _inputPath,
            int     _inputWidth,
            int     _inputHeight,
            int     _patternOffset,
            int     _patternSkipEach,
            int     _patternAngleRadian,
            int     _patternBlockAmount,
            int     _patternNumber,
            int[]   _patternColor
    ) {
        super(
                _idReadable,
                _runThisLayer,
                _inputPath
        );

        inputWidth          = _inputWidth;
        inputHeight         = _inputHeight;
        patternOffset       = _patternOffset;
        patternSkipEach     = _patternSkipEach;
        patternAngleRadian  = _patternAngleRadian;
        patternBlockAmount  = _patternBlockAmount;
        patternNumber       = _patternNumber;
        patternColor        = _patternColor;
    }
}
```

**LayerHalftoneVideo.java**

```
public class LayerHalftoneVideo extends LayerHalftone {

    public static int       videoTimeStart;
    public static float     videoTimeSpeed;

    public LayerHalftoneVideo(
            String  _idReadable,
            boolean _runThisLayer,
            String  _inputPath,
            int     _inputWidth,
            int     _inputHeight,
            int     _patternOffset,
            int     _patternSkipEach,
            int     _patternAngleRadian,
            int     _patternBlockAmount,
            int     _patternNumber,
            int[]   _patternColor,
            int     _videoTimeStart,
            float   _videoTimeSpeed
    ) {
        super(
                _idReadable,
                _runThisLayer,
                _inputPath,
                _inputWidth,
                _inputHeight,
                _patternOffset,
                _patternSkipEach,
                _patternAngleRadian,
                _patternBlockAmount,
                _patternNumber,
                _patternColor
        );

        videoTimeStart  = _videoTimeStart;
        videoTimeSpeed  = _videoTimeSpeed;
    }

}
```

**LayerHalftoneImage.java**

```
public class LayerHalftoneImage extends LayerHalftone {

    public LayerHalftoneImage(
            String  _idReadable,
            boolean _runThisLayer,
            String  _inputPath,
            int     _inputWidth,
            int     _inputHeight,
            int     _patternOffset,
            int     _patternSkipEach,
            int     _patternAngleRadian,
            int     _patternBlockAmount,
            int     _patternNumber,
            int[]   _patternColor
    ) {
        super(
                _idReadable,
                _runThisLayer,
                _inputPath,
                _inputWidth,
                _inputHeight,
                _patternOffset,
                _patternSkipEach,
                _patternAngleRadian,
                _patternBlockAmount,
                _patternNumber,
                _patternColor
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: All your fields are static...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks all! I'll do some reading on your pointers! I appreciate it

Comment: @Sweeper, thanks! That was it! The static variables from the upperClass Layers where the problem. It all works like it should now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your `Layer` and its subclasses:

```
public abstract class Layer {

    static String    idReadable;
    static boolean   runThisLayer;
    static String    inputPath;
    ...
}
```

You'll see that they all have `static` fields. These fields belong to the class, not the instances of the class that you create. Therefore, the different layers you create will not have independent `idReadable`, `runThisLayer` or `inputPath`s. Each time a new layer gets created, these fields get reset, which is why they only contain the values of the last layer you create.

To fix this, just make them non-static:

```
public abstract class Layer {

    String    idReadable;
    boolean   runThisLayer;
    String    inputPath;
    ...
}
```

You should also consider making them private and using getters to get their value instead.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks for the pointer. I'll read up to statics